# How to abort getchar() command in C?

Tags: c, windows, console-application, getchar

I am basically a beginner C++ programmer...and it's my first attempt to code in C.

I am trying to program a snake game (using `system ("cls")`).

In this program I need to get a character as an input (basically to let the user change the direction of movement of snake)... and if the use doesn't input any character within half a second then this character input command needs to be aborted and my remaining code should get executed.

Please give suggestions to sort out this problem.

> EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions, but
>   **My main motive of asking this question was to find a method to abort the getchar command even if the user has not entered anything....Any suggestions on this?  And by the way my platform is windows**

Comment: C? Objective-c? C++? Please decide. Anyway, you need to use POSIX or platform methods.

Comment: You shouldn't use `system("cls")` to clear the screen, it's non-portable and it spawns a whole new process(or two?) just to clear the screen, for POSIX-compliant platforms take a look at ncurses.

Comment: Why do you tag this as objective C? It clearly isn't about Objective C.

Comment: You can check for available keyboard input using [`_kbhit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx).

Comment: @eryksun Thanks bro your idea works....can you plz post this as an answer, so that I can close this question by accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the best suited answer to my question in comments, which was posted by @eryksun.

The best way is to use a function [kbhit()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx) (part of conio.h).

Answer (score 3):

The best way, in my opinion, is using libncurses.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

You have all the tools to make a snake easily.

If you think it's too easy (it is a relatively high level library), look at the termcaps library.

EDIT: So, a non-blocking read with termcaps is :

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <term.h>

uintmax_t          getchar()
{
  uintmax_t        key = 0;

  read(0, &key, sizeof(key));
  return key;
}

int                main(int ac, char **av, char **env)
{
  char             *name_term;
  struct termios   term;

  if ((name_term = getenv("TERM")) == NULL) // looking for name of term
     return (-1);
  if (tgetent(NULL, &name_term) == ERR) // get possibilities of term
     return (-1);
  term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
  term.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; term.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; // non-blocking read
  if (tcgetattr(0, term) == -1) // applying modifications.
     return (-1);
  /* Your code here with getchar() */
  term.c_lflag &= (ICANON | ECHO);
  if (tcgetattr(0, term) == -1) // applying modifications.
     return (-1);
  return (0);
}
```

EDIT 2:
You have to compile with

> -lncurses

option.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this on a UNIX-like platform (such as Linux) is to use the `select` function. You can find its documentation [online](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select). I'm not sure if this function is available on Windows; you didn't specify an operating system.

Comment: `system("cls")` works on Windows; it doesn't work by default on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still struggling, assuming you use **ncurses**, your timeout may expand to the rest of the getch() calls, and thus terminates your program earlier than you want.

timeout() set its condition for all getch() calls in the program.

Try to disable the timeout after the getch() that you **want** to timeout, has been timeout'd.

```
while(condition) {
    timeout(3000);
    c = getch();
    if(c = ERR){
        timeout(-1); // timeout goes back to block on getch()'s!
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can spawn a new thread that can emulate pressing of the Enter Key after 30 seconds.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

void ThreadProc()
{
    // Sleep for 30 seconds
    Sleep(30*1000);
    // Press and release enter key
    keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0x9C, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0x9C, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}


int main()
{
    DWORD dwThreadId;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadProc, NULL, 0,&dwThreadId);
    char key = getchar();
    // you are out of getchar now. You can check the 'key' for a value of '10' to see if the thread did it. 
    // Kill thread before you do getchar again
}
```

Be careful with this technique, specially if you do geatchar() in a loop, otherwise you might end up with lot of threads pressing ENTER key! Be sure to kill the thread before you start getchar() again.